# Bootstrap 3 Row Not Lining Up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having an issue with some markup with Bootstrap 3. My labels and text are not lining up. Here's my markup and a picture of what is visually happening.

http://www.bootply.com/a1pIGBa50d

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
            <label for="Status">
                Status: 
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p name="Status" class="form-control-static">
                Approved
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" ......
```

[image: bootstrap 3 line up issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `.form-control-static` from the `<p>` tag.

I might suggest you consider using description lists for this type of formatting. See http://www.bootply.com/qKHHFjjCVT for a working example, and code below:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>Status:</dt>
  <dd>Approved</dd>
  <dt>Date:</dt>
  <dd>2014-06-30 00:30:00.0</dd>
  <dt>Originator:</dt>
  <dd>ADMIN</dd>
  <dt>Phone:</dt>
  <dd>None</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just apply this because paragraph tag is applying padding

```
.form-control-static { padding: 0;}
```

or you can remove

```
.form-control-static
```